# Let T: $P_2 \to P_2 $ be defined by $(Tf)(t) = f'(t)(3+t) + 2f(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find out the values for the following inputs: $1, t, t^2.$
I get my values for 1, which is simply 2. However, I am having a hard time figuring out the outputs for the other inputs. For $t$, I get $1 + 2t$ and for $t^2$ I get $6 + 2t + 2t^2$. Am I doing my transformation wrong? I'm ultimately  trying to find the matrix that represents this transformation which is suppose to be 
$$
\begin{matrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end {matrix}
$$
I see how we get my first column but I'm confused about the other two. Thank-you very much.

Comment: In the future, instead of using ->, use \to in your $\LaTeX$ to make $\to$. $->$ is a bit unseemly.

Comment: Are you sure your supposed answer is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f(t)=t$,

$$T(f(t))=1\cdot (3+t)+2\cdot t=3+3t$$

So the second column is $(3,3,0)$, since $3+3t=3\cdot 1+3\cdot t+0\cdot t^2$. Can you use the same way to find the third column?

Comment: yup I wasn't doing the transformation right. For some reason I forgot how functions work. For example, for t squared, I was taking the derivative of that and then inserting (3 + t) into that.  Thanks a lot!